# Execute php in crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, server

I have a usr/local/bin/test.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv.zip
wget -P /tmp/stat/ http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip
rm -f /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv
unzip -d /tmp/stat/ /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv.zip
php test.php /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv
```

I'm trying to run it on a server, using crontab. Code in/etc/crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/tmp/stat
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

25 12 * * * root /usr/local/bin/test.sh
```

.zipped file gets downloaded and unzipped (very slowly, but it gets done). My test.php file is supposed to collect data from the file and insert it into a mysql database. test.
If I execute test.sh in the terminal, everything is fine. But nothing gets written in the database through cron job. Why is this? I don't even know if it starts ezecuting test.php at all.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PATH variable in cron is not the one you get when logging in. Simple enough: cron does not log you (nor any other user) in.

Similarly, you have a current directory when logging in that's not all that likely to be the same that's going to get used by root's cron jobs.

Simplest and most robust solution is to add full paths in front of all commands such as php, unzip, wget ...
AND to cd to the directory you need to be in.

To find out which path you use when you're executing commands while logged in, use "which":

So e.g.:

```
$ which php
/weird/place/php
```

Would mean you replace the line `php test.php /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv` with `/weird/place/php test.php /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv` and similarly, add the location to the script test.php just as well. so you end up with something like `/weird/place/php /home/user/subdir/test.php /tmp/stat/top-1m.csv`

Normally a unix system is setup to email the output of cronjobs to the user who owns the crontab. Might be root in your case from the looks of it. Check that email and try to get it delivered to you so you can see these errors and react to them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute path for test.php in test.sh

Answer (score 1):

When Running a crontab it's allways recomended to provide full paths to your executing programs, for example

```
/usr/bin/php ...
```

rather than

```
php ...
```

And

```
full/path/to/test.php
```

You should also check if your cron user has permissions to acces that file.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a correct answer too, but I can only mark one